# How to join two tables by dates?

Tags: ms-access, office365

I have two tables imported into Access from Excel workbooks.

They are narrow tables:

```
INRMaster:      MastDate       Date/Time (Short Date)

CIInput:        CIDate         Date/Time (Short Date)
                INRTestResult  Number
                Dose           Number
                OutOfRange     Short Text
```

CIInput table was downloaded and the date was date/time with date and time of test.  I reformatted that date field to mm:dd:yyyy to match the table I created, INRMaster.

There is no primary key on either table.  I tried the join with primary keys of date in both tables and it returned nothing as well.  Creating the query using the QBE Grid.

The generated SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT INRMaster.MastDate, CIINput.[INR test result], CIINput.Dose, CIINput.OutofRange
FROM INRMaster INNER JOIN CIINput ON INRMaster.MastDate = CIINput.CIDate
```

Office 365 Access, Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Setting Format property does not change data. Unless you actually modify saved values, time part is still there and since it is unlikely values will agree to the second, a join will fail. Don't apply formatting in table - view full saved value.

Extract date part with expression in query. If both fields were saved with date and time components, then extract date portion from both. Consider:

```
SELECT INRMaster.MastDate, CIINput.[INR test result], CIINput.Dose, CIINput.OutofRange
FROM INRMaster INNER JOIN CIINput ON Int(INRMaster.MastDate) = Int(CIINput.CIDate);
```

DO NOT OPEN QUERY IN DESIGN VIEW. Query Designer cannot resolve this join. Would have to join nested subqueries to enable Design View.

Comment: Got it fixed. Thanks

Comment: The performance of this is not very good tho, i'd probably create new columns to join on. If you want design view you could wrap the tables into views with an extra field Int(INRMaster.MastDate) ,  before this query.